# Como fazer uma aplicação em dois idiomas mudando o idioma no menu settings? Android studio

Tags: android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] Eu gostaria de fazer isso manualmente através de um click, Idioma Português ou inglês. e buscar a string correta.

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor maneira de fazer isso seria adicionando diferentes strings.xml em diferentes pastas de recursos, exemplo:

```
res/
    values/
           strings.xml // Idioma padrão 
    values-pt-rBr/
           strings.xml // Idioma português Brasil
```

Mais na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization) do Android.

Ou você pode mudar manualmente como o exemplo [deste site](https://blog.guillaumeagis.eu/change-language/).

Comment: Quando vou criar a pasta values-en por exemplo, ele fica oculta!

Comment: Se estiver no Android Studio normalmente fica oculta até adicionar algum arquivo la dentro, eu costumo fazer isso mudando o modo de exibição do projeto de android pra project ou simplesmente fazendo isso manualmente através do explorador de arquivos do Windows. Depois você vera na pasta values no projeto uma pasta strings, que mostrará seus arquivos de strings.

Comment: Bom! adicionei! agora falta mesmo o tópico da pergunta.como alterar de um para outro.

Comment: Geralmente o Android escolhe o idioma do seu aplicativo baseado nos seus strings.xml, no segundo link, o author do post mostra como criar um método para mudar o idioma